# How is the name of this Dataframe method?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way to categorize numerical data in the following way

Given

```
   A  B  C
0  2  4  2
1  3  4  4
2  4  2  1
3  5  2  5
```

transform to :

```
   Category  Value
0         A      2
1         A      3
2         A      4
3         A      5
4         B      4
5         B      4
6         B      2
7         B      2
8         C      2
9         C      4
10        C      1
11        C      5
```

I know that there exists a pd.Df method but I just cannot find it anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That is melt function of pandas.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

Comment: don't post link only answer atleast post an example